# SPI transfer fails with buffer size greater than 4096

Tags: spi

I'm trying to 8192 bytes over SPI in a single transfer, but for some reason anything over 4096 bytes fails to send. How can I enable larger data transfers?

```
int ret;

uint8_t txn[] = { 0x00, ... };

struct spi_ioc_transfer tr = {
    .tx_buf = (unsigned long)txn,
    .len = (unsigned int)sizeof(txn),
    .delay_usecs = 0,
    .speed_hz = 10000000,
    .bits_per_word = 8,
};

ret = ioctl(fd, SPI_IOC_MESSAGE(1), &tr);
if (ret < 1)
    pabort("Can't send SPI message");
```

I'm working with the Raspberry Pi Zero W if it matters.

Comment: I had follow this tutorial and the problem had fixed: https://youtu.be/1VJDhAClKMc.
Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As you have noticed the default maximum SPI transfer is 4096 bytes with the standard Linux driver.

To change the default add `spidev.bufsiz=65536` to `/boot/cmdline.txt` and reboot.  Where 65536 is the maximum size you want to allow.

Note that `/boot/cmdline.txt` is a single line.  After the above change mine looked like:

```
dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 console=tty1 root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline fsck.repair=yes spidev.bufsiz=65536 rootwait logo.nologo
```

As an aside my pigpio SPI driver defaults to a buffer size of 64k.

Comment: I've done this but still get a the 4096 limit error.

Comment: @Gilad I suggest you open a new question detailing exactly what you have done and any error messages you receive.  Also try to explain why your set up might be different to the original questioner.

Comment: What is this limitation good for?  Except for making me lose 4 hours for troubleshooting, because one of the blocks was 4736 bytes long?