# Extending the SPI buffer size beyond 65536 bytes

Tags: spi

I am trying to use the Raspberry Pi 4 model B to program the Lattice ICE40 FPGA chip via SPI. It requires continuous clock signal throughout the whole transmission of the bitfile, which is easily bigger than 1Mb.

I am using the spidev library and thanks to the following posts:

[SPI transfer fails with buffer size greater than 4096](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/65595/spi-transfer-fails-with-buffer-size-greater-than-4096)

[How to transfer large amount of data (100Kbytes) over SPI?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/131996/how-to-transfer-large-amount-of-data-100kbytes-over-spi)

I was able to configure the buffer size to a bigger number. However even after this, the transmission is still split after 65536 bytes no matter the buffer size setting in `/boot/cmdline.txt`

Where does this limitation come from? Can it be bypassed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that this limitation is set directly in spidev and it has its reason:

https://github.com/doceme/py-spidev/issues/62#issuecomment-422475465

Indeed, it looks like that the maximum supported transfer length is limited by the device driver, which can be seen right there:

https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/blob/bfef951a177d4d3f10e8b5072316a517d68a2a27/drivers/spi/spi-bcm2835.c#L371C1-L371C1

I am not sure whether fixing this would be as easy as changing the value and recompiling the driver as I am going to instead bitbang the bitmap myself.

EDIT:

So I've spent some more time on this and found, that the 65535 bytes limit is unfortunately definitive right now. The reason for this is that the register `DLEN` which holds the data length inside the CPU is 16-bit. This has been the case for the first BCM2835 CPU used in RPi 1 and still remains the case for the BCM2711 in RPi 4.

This can be found in the CPU datasheet here (page 139):

https://datasheets.raspberrypi.com/bcm2711/bcm2711-peripherals.pdf

**You can still remove the constrain in the spidev code (`spidev_module.c` line 47) and this will work, however the driver will not use DMA for this and thus the transfer speed can be significantly limited.**

Comment: Suggest you mark your answer as "Selected" as this may help others struggling with the same issue.